# how to publish .net core project in visual studio include View and area Folders

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2019, publish

i have problem after publish my Project(.net core 2.2) in visual studio 2019

after publish no exist View Folder and Area Folder in Published Files. how to publish my project include view and area folders?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit your.csproj file and add PreserveCompilationContext as true and MvcRazorCompileOnPublish as false

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.0</TargetFramework>
<PreserveCompilationContext>true</PreserveCompilationContext>
<MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>false</MvcRazorCompileOnPublish>
</PropertyGroup>
```

then views will be included in publish